# get error message from unsuccessful Google Compute Engine instance start

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using the below code to start an instance. The code works as expected and starts an instance.

However, if `$service->instances->start` fails to start an instance due to an error at GCP end, I wont receive any notice. It will execute without any exceptions thrown. I've tested this by trying to run 2 instances with more then 8 cpus in a single zone (the free account is not allowed to own more than 8 cores in a zone). While the instances never started, I didn't receive any error in this script.

How can I recover from a general starting error? Should I use timers to check a minute later if everything is running as expected? Is there a more robust way of starting instances?

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google-ComputeSample/0.1');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');

    $service = new Google_Service_Compute($client);

    $project = 'project_id';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
    $zone = 'us-east1-b';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
    $instance = 'instance-1';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    $response = $service->instances->start($project, $zone, $instance);

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";
```

On the other hand, CLI equivalent command `gcloud compute instances start instance-1 --zone=us-east1-b` does return an error. Is it possible to get the error message in PHP as well?

Error message in CLI:

```
Starting instance(s) instance-2...failed.                                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) Quota 'CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 8.0 in region us-east1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the json tags of the [response body](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start) to retrieve the error content. If you still don't see any output, you can file an issue [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under 'Developer Tools'.